# Is there any way to check Bounce Rate in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics-4

When I tried to view it in custom reports, the loading animation keeps playing and I found an js error pops out:

[image]

The issue reproduces no matter how many times I purge cache, log out and log in back.

Is it because GA4 is still under construction? Is there any other way I can view the Bounce Rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try to add a dimension. Like a landing page.
- Try in incognito. Adblockers and other plugins might easily interfere with the site.
- Try
  removing extra metrics.
- Try changing the date range, say, to the
  previous week.

Explore view is better than reports in terms of it dealing with the real data and not aggregated snapshots, but it won't let you easily pair any dimensions to any metric like you would in BQ or Adobe Analytics. Still Beta, in essence. Full of pretty much silent errors like that.

Comment: I just did add a dimension and it works. Thanks very much.